# the discrete family of closed sets cover

Tags: general-topology

When I study on the proof of every paracompact space is collectionwise normal, I have problem.
Let $X$ be a paracompact space and $\{F_s\}_s\in S$ be a discrete family of closed subsets of $X$. Then for each $x\in X$, we can choose a neighbourhood $H_x$ of the point $x$ whose closure meets at most one set $F_s$. But how? we don't know the family of closed discrete sets covers $X$? How can we say for each $x$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the space is Hausdorff, it’s just the definition of *discrete collection*.

> A collection $\mathscr{D}$ of subsets of a space $X$ is discrete if and only if for each $x\in X$ there is an open nbhd $U_x$ of $x$ such that $U_x$ meets at most one member of $\mathscr{D}$.

Now use the fact that a Hausdorff paracompact space is regular to conclude that there is an open set $V_x$ such that $x\in V_x\subseteq\operatorname{cl}V_x\subseteq U_x$.

Comment: No, I mean that how can you say $X$ is a discrete space. You can just say for every $x\in D\in \mathcal{D}$,there exists a neighbourhood $U_x$.....

Comment: @user89330: I don’t understand: no one is saying that $X$ is a discrete space.

Comment: I mean that every point of $X$ is isolated point? No.   You should just say for every point of $D\in \mathcal {D}$ is isolated point.

Comment: @user89330: No: the elements of $\mathscr{D}$ need not be points. I suspect that you don’t understand what a discrete family is. $\{[2n,2n+1]:n\in\Bbb Z\}$ is a discrete family of closed sets in $\Bbb R$, because for each $x\in\Bbb R$ the open interval $\left(x-\frac14,x+\frac14\right)$ meets at most one of those closed intervals.

Comment: For every $D\in \mathcal{D}$ is discrete subset in $X$. So, every point of $D$ is isolated point in $X$. In the proof, we can find a cover of $X$ which is important in the proof. my question is every point of $x\in X$ isolated point? otherwise, how can we cover $X$

Comment: @user89330: No, that is **not** what it means for $\mathscr{D}$ to be a discrete collection. The members of $\mathscr{D}$ do **not** have to be discrete. And $\mathscr{D}$ is **not** in general a cover of the space.

Comment: So, ı could not understand the proof. could you explain how we can find a cover of $X$, if possible

Comment: @user89330: Hold on for a couple of minutes while I finish answering another question.

Comment: ohh, I see. Because of the definition of discrete family, we can find an open neighbourhood for each $x\in X$.I think I mixed the definition of the discrete sets and the discrete family.These are different.

Comment: thanks. one more question, if we have a countable point finite open family( covers $X$), can we find a development for $X$?

Comment: @user89330: Not in general, no: $\{X\}$ is always a countable point-finite open cover of $X$. Did you mean a stronger condition?

Comment: I think that if I have a countable point finite cover, for each $x$, I can find  finite basic set $B_i$ in any base, which contained  $x\in X$. The union of the basic sets  can be base. by using this base can we find a development?

Comment: @user89330: It’s harder than that. Let $Y$ be any space that is not developable, and let $X=\Bbb N\times Y$, where $\Bbb N$ has the discrete topology. Then $\{\{n\}\times Y:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is a point-finite open cover of $X$, but $X$ is not developable.

Comment: I mean that, by using base can I construct a development in general?

Comment: what is the most comman way to construct a development? Could you advise any reference book?

Comment: @user89330: I’m still really not sure just what construction you have in mind to get the development, or what you’re assuming about the space. Are you assuming that the space is metacompact (every open cover has a point-finite open refinement)?

Comment: No, I just wonder the relation with the base and the development.

Comment: @user89330: I don’t know of any good book treatment of the topic. You might try searching the literature on the so-called *normal Moore space conjecture*: a Moore space is a $T_3$ developable space, so most of the spaces that you’ll encounter are developable.

Comment: @user89330: To begin with, every developable space is first countable, so you need that right away. But developability is really a pretty strong property, and there aren’t any simple ways to get it just starting with first countability. // You’re very welcome.